# Question closed as Game-Rec (and now has a delete vote)

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

My question [Updated guide for skill leveling order?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315745/updated-guide-for-skill-leveling-order) gathered a few close votes soon after posting.

I was asking for a similar quick reference/ cheat sheet to the outdated one shown there. When I asked why it was being downvoted and getting close votes, luckily someone explained that

> We don't accept recommendation questions: be for asking for games or for cheat sheets

Fair enough, I do know this already. So I went back and edited the title & text to clarify that I am interested in the leveling order of skills for these champs, which can be useful for someone playing them for the first time.

However it still ended up getting closed with *Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware are off topic.* Now I see that there is also a vote to delete it.

The only thing I can think of is the phrase

> Is there any similar reference with more recent data available?

that might imply that I'm not expecting it to be answered on the site itself, which isn't the case. But it still doesn't seem enough reason to close the question, so I would like to know how it is out of scope for the site and how/whether that can be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a request for an external resource which is problematic in itself but doesn't quite make it a 'Shopping Recommendation', which is off-topic for a bunch of reasons mainly to do with them being 'opinion based' as well as the rapid obsolescence of shopping advice.

The **main** problem is there are a **lot** of playable heroes, too much for a single question to cover, which is the definition of 'Too Broad'. Thus while I disagree with the 'Shopping Rec' close reason at the end of the day the question as it stands just isn't a good fit for us and should remain closed in its current state.

If there is a particular hero you are having difficulty with and want an overview of, we can help with that, but large, hard to maintain, exhaustive guides just aren't our forte.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shopping recommendation, which we also classify as "game recommendation".

Basically, you're asking to find something that fits a criteria, this can be the best hardware for some money, a game choice between two games, a list of games of a certain type, a game recommendation request or, well, a request to find an updated version of said cheat sheet, doesn't matter, it's still a shopping/game recommendation request, which is banned, and the proper close vote for it is still "game recommendation".

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly a shopping rec, it's mostly extremely broad. And should have been closed for being super broad.

Comment: @Arperum it's "shopping" for a new version of said cheat sheet. I see your point, but I believe both close reasons apply here

Comment: If I hadn't mentioned the cheat sheet as example, and just asked for a guide to figuring out skill order for new heroes - would it be different then?